# Unset css property "inherit"

Tags: css, vuetify.js

I am using a framework (vuetify) which by default inserts the following css rule:

```
[type="button"] {
  color: inherit;
}
```

The problem is that this is always inserted at last and I cannot control that. So if I am using the html `<button type="button" class="button">Test</button>` with the style `.button { color: red; }`, the css rule is not used because it gets overriden by the other rule. This means that for all button classes I either have to use another selector like `button.button` or I have to use `!important`. Is there another way to globally disable the property `color: inherit` so that I can still use a class like `.button` without using a more restrictive selector?

Comment: since it's inherit, target the parent element to set the coloration you want

Comment: So you say I should add the color property to the element `body`? This does not seem right to me.

Comment: not the body, the closest parent to your button element

Comment: Yes, thats the body. What I can do is to insert a wrapper `div` around any button, so that I can put the color to that element.

Comment: Or you just put `button.button` not to create a wrapper around a element to just give it a color. There is no point in doing that. FYI not saying Temani is wrong just saying about your last comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can get around it by not putting `type="button"` on your buttons, it has that (button) behaviour by "default".

```css
.button {
  color: deepskyblue;
}

.container {
  color: deeppink;
}

[type="button"] {
  color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button class="button" type="button">What color will I have?</button>

  <button class="button">What color will I have?</button>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not true. Only in IE the default is `type="button"`, see https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_pushbutton_type.asp

Comment: Well unless you have a form around it is. Thats why I put "default" in quotes and used "get around". Is your button inside a form? @MatthewDarton

Comment: Some are, some are not. So I guess I have to look for some other solution.

Comment: @MatthewDarton Don't take this the wrong way but to be honest seems as you are making a bigger deal of this then it needs to be. Use `button.button` in those cases. Or for buttons that are inside a form put `type="submit` and you are good to go, unless there is styling for that? If it is, you will be good with `button.button` This is the trade of you make when using a "style framework", you would probably have to do core stuff to vuetify to exlude that rule, and that seems... [go back to row one]